# How to plot a quarter disk with specified height?

Tags: plotting, visualization

Kind of important: the solution posted does work, and answers the question in that sense. However, it is very slow, so a faster option would be much appreciated.

I'm trying to create the following image in Mathematica. 
[image]

I apologize for my terrible paint skills. The idea is that I have a certain vector, say $({0,-\sqrt{0.25},\sqrt{0.5},-\sqrt0.25})$ (it's a unit vector, apart from that the components can take any real value). Now, what I want is to plot a disk, where each quarter section corresponds to a value of the vector. So in the image I drew, the first component is 0, so that quarter is just a quarter circle in the z = 0 plane. Then the second component would have height $\sqrt{0.25}$ in the second quarter section of the disk, in the negative z direction, et cetera.

Now, to be honest, I'm not sure where to start. I first thought I could possible use ParametricPlot3D, for example like

```
ParametricPlot3D[{ Cos[u], Sin[u], v}, {u, 0, 2 Pi/4}, {v, -0.5, 0}, 
 Mesh -> None]
```

However, this only draws the outer shell, and I'm not sure to fill it up. Nor am I sure that I can combine this with another 3 commands in order to get a full disk, but perhaps that is not too difficult. In any case, I was wondering if someone had an idea of how to do this, and if I'm taking the right approach.

To extend a little on this, I tried combining them like this but it doesn't seem to work

```
p1 = ParametricPlot3D[{ Cos[u], Sin[u], v}, {u, 0, 2 Pi/4}, {v, -0.5, 
    0}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5]];
p2 = ParametricPlot3D[{ Cos[u], Sin[u], v}, {u, 2 Pi/4, 2 Pi/2}, {v, 
    0, Sqrt[0.5]}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> LightBlue];
Show[p1, p2]
```

I can however do it in 2D, with circles. If only here was an easy way to plot sections of cylinders.

```
p1 = Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, 0, {0, 2 Pi/4}]}];
p2 = Graphics[{Red, Disk[{0, 0}, Sqrt[0.5], {2 Pi/4, 2 Pi/2}]}];
p3 = Graphics[{Blue, Disk[{0, 0}, 0.5, {Pi, 3/2*Pi}]}];
p4 = Graphics[{Red, Disk[{0, 0}, Sqrt[0.5], {3/2*Pi, 2 Pi/1}]}];
Show[p1, p2, p3, p4]
```

Comment: Actually, I think using Cylinder would be better than doing it parameterically, I suppose. If I can do quarter cylinders..

Comment: Also, I should note that I'm not looking at the option for just 4 cuboids arranged into a larger cuboid; I need to be able to do this for 3 or 5 components as well, so something with a variable angle is really needed.

Comment: I thought Cylinder would be the way to go as well. But when I looked at the documentation I found that although Disk has a list of angles as an optional argument enabling one to plot a sector, Cylinder did not appear to have that option.

Comment: Your example with Show[p1,p1] will work. You need to specify the PlotRange so that it all can be seen. Without an explicit PlotRange Show takes on the range of the first plot.    Show[p1, p2, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}} ] works fine.

Comment: Ah, stupid, thanks. Still, it doesn't fill all the way to the origin sadly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a rather fast function to create a section of a cylinder of a given height combining some `ParametricPlot3D` using the following code:

```
cylinderSection[h_, \[Theta]0_, \[Theta]1_, 
  OptionsPattern[plotStyle -> Green]] := With[{r = 1},
  Show[
   ParametricPlot3D[
    {{\[Rho] Cos[\[Theta]], \[Rho] Sin[\[Theta]], 0},
     {\[Rho] Cos[\[Theta]], \[Rho] Sin[\[Theta]], h}},
    {\[Rho], 0, r},
    {\[Theta], \[Theta]0, \[Theta]1},
    Mesh -> None,
    PlotStyle -> OptionValue@plotStyle
    ],
   ParametricPlot3D[
    {Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]], z},
    {\[Theta], \[Theta]0, \[Theta]1},
    {z, 0, h},
    Mesh -> None,
    PlotStyle -> OptionValue@plotStyle
    ],
   ParametricPlot3D[
    {{t Cos[\[Theta]0], t Sin[\[Theta]0], z},
     {t Cos[\[Theta]1], t Sin[\[Theta]1], z}},
    {t, 0, 1},
    {z, 0, h},
    Mesh -> None,
    PlotStyle -> OptionValue@plotStyle
    ],
   PlotRange -> All,
   RotationAction -> "Clip",
   ImageSize -> Large
   ]
  ]
```

This is called in exactly the same way as the solution with `RegionPlot3D` (see below):

```
Show[
 cylinderSection[0.001, 0, Pi/2, plotStyle -> Blue],
 cylinderSection[-Sqrt[0.25], Pi/2, Pi, plotStyle -> Green],
 cylinderSection[Sqrt[0.5], -Pi, -Pi/2, plotStyle -> Orange],
 cylinderSection[-Sqrt[0.25], -Pi/2, 0, plotStyle -> Red]
 ]
```

And this is the output:

[image]

You want the whole thing generated by only giving as input heights, angles and colors? Do it with the function `makePie`:

```
makePie[hh_List, angles_List, plotStyles_List] := Show[
  Append[
   Table[
    cylinderSection[hh[[i]] /. (0 -> 0.001), angles[[i]], 
     angles[[i + 1]], plotStyle -> plotStyles[[i]]],
    {i, Length@hh - 1}
    ],
   cylinderSection[hh[[Length@hh]] /. (0 -> 0.001), 
    angles[[Length@hh]], 2 Pi, plotStyle -> plotStyles[[Length@hh]]]
   ]
  ]
```

You can now generate the above pie with the following:

```
makePie[{0, -Sqrt[0.25], Sqrt[0.5], -Sqrt[0.25]}, {0, Pi/2, Pi, 
  3 Pi/2}, {Blue, Green, Orange, Red}]
```

But you can use it to generate pies with an arbitrary number of partitions, not just four.
For fun, you can try this:

```
With[{n = RandomInteger@{3, 20}}, 
 makePie[RandomReal[{-2, 2}, n], Sort@RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, n], 
  RandomColor@n]]
```

[image]

#### The (slow) solution I originally found, using `RegionPlot3D`:

First create a function drawing an arbitrary section of a cylinder with

```
cylinderSection[h_, \[Theta]1_, \[Theta]2_, 
  OptionsPattern[plotStyle -> Red]] := RegionPlot3D[
  x^2 + y^2 < 1 &&
   \[Theta]1 < ArcTan[x, y] < \[Theta]2,
  {x, -1, 1},
  {y, -1, 1},
  {z, 0, h},
  Mesh -> None,
  PlotRange -> All,
  RotationAction -> "Clip",
  PlotStyle -> OptionValue@plotStyle,
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  ImageSize -> Large
  ]
```

Then combine it with `Show` to obtain the desired result.

```
Show[
 cylinderSection[0.001, 0, Pi/2, plotStyle -> Blue],
 cylinderSection[-Sqrt[0.25], Pi/2, Pi, plotStyle -> Green],
 cylinderSection[Sqrt[0.5], -Pi, -Pi/2, plotStyle -> Orange],
 cylinderSection[-Sqrt[0.25], -Pi/2, 0, plotStyle -> Red]
 ]
```

[image]

Unfortunately, this has the problem of being rather slow, so possibly something better with only `Graphics3D` can be realized.

Comment: Very interesting, I'll have a look at this!

Comment: @user129412 I edited the code, the colors should work now. For the slowness you can lower the value of `PlotPoints`, but at the cost of output quality.

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, but is there a specific reason for not making the empty quarter with your function too? As it seems to create some strange overlay effects with the other ones. I have to admit it does look quite good!

Comment: @user129412 no reason at all! The overlay effect is because I included a disk (actually a very thin cylinder) surrounding the pie region, which seemed to be what you wanted from your drawing, but I had to make it opaque so to allow one to see through it. I admit the styling of the thing could be improved though.

Comment: I see, yeah that's just vagueness from my picture then, I'm sorry. It is indeed very much what I'm looking for; problem is I'll need to plot about 4 of these in a row about 20 times (different vector values, it's an eigenvector visualization) so the speed is rough. But, it is definitely better than nothing. I'll keep it open for a bit to see if someone has a faster way, but if not I'll accept it!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Something I thought would be an easy addition (not a requirement, just something I thought of) was variable opacity for each of them. That would go in the function I suppose, but RegionPlot3D doesn't seem to have an opacity option?

Comment: @user129412 the opacity settings can be included in the `PlotStyle` option. The way I defined `cylinderSection` you can pass to `PlotStyle` whatever you want through `plotStyle`. For example to have the green region opaque you can use `cylinderSection[-Sqrt[0.25], Pi/2, Pi, 
 plotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Green]]`

Comment: Very impressive. Thanks so much.

Comment: It is absolutely fantastic that you were able to do this. I'd like to bother you with one more small issue though.. Lets take the following code. As you will see, there are some rather ugly intersections between the four. Do you have an idea as to how to avoid this?
makePie[{-Sqrt[0.25], -Sqrt[0.25], -Sqrt[0.25], -Sqrt[0.25]}, {0, 
  Pi/2, Pi, 3 Pi/2}, {RGBColor[1, 0, 0, 0.3], RGBColor[1, 0, 0, 0.3], 
  RGBColor[1, 0, 0, 0.3], RGBColor[1, 0, 0, 0.3]}]

Comment: @user129412 I'm not sure how to fix that I'm afraid. But you could maybe ask how to fix that problem on a separate question, as it seems interesting enough.

Answer (score 2):

```
seg[{a_, b_}, {g_, h_}, col_, op_] := 
 Show[ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t], Sin[t], z}, {t, a, b}, {z, g, h}, 
   Mesh -> False, PlotStyle -> {col, Opacity[op]}, 
   BoundaryStyle -> {Black, Thick}], 
  ParametricPlot3D[{u Cos[t], u Sin[t], g}, {t, a, b}, {u, 0, 1}, 
   Mesh -> False, PlotStyle -> {col, Opacity[op]}], 
  ParametricPlot3D[{u Cos[t], u Sin[t], h}, {t, a, b}, {u, 0, 1}, 
   Mesh -> False, PlotStyle -> {col, Opacity[op]}], 
  Graphics3D[{col, Opacity[op], EdgeForm[{Black, Thick}], 
      Polygon[{{0, 0, g}, {0, 0, h}, {Cos[#], Sin[#], h}, {Cos[#], 
         Sin[#], g}}]} & /@ {a, b}]]
```

Visualizing:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[seg[{0 + a, Pi/2}, {0, 1}, Red, opacity], 
  seg[{-Pi/2, Pi + a}, {-1, 0}, Blue, opacity],
  seg[{Pi + a, 3 Pi/2}, {-.01, 0}, Gray, opacity],
  PlotRange -> Table[{-2, 2}, {3}], Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
  Background -> White], {opacity, 0.3, 1}, {{a, 0}, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### ChartElementData["CylindricalSector3D"]

The built-in  function `ChartElementData["CylindricalSector3D"]`
takes two or more arguments. The first argument, `{{angle0_, angle1_}, {radius0_, radius1_}, {height0_, height1_}}` specifies the angles, radii and heights needed to specify a cylindrical sector. The second argument needs to be specified but can be anything for our application. We use this function to generate the graphics primitives in the following function:

```
cylindricalSectors[styles : {__}, specs : {__}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Graphics3D[{#, EdgeForm[], ChartElementData["CylindricalSector3D"][#2, {}]} & @@@ 
   Transpose[{styles, specs}], opts, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

**Examples:**

```
cylindricalSectors[{Red}, {{{Pi/2, Pi}, {0, 1}, {0, 1/2}}},  Axes -> True]
```

[image]

```
specs = {{{0, Pi/2}, {0, 2}, {0, 1}}, {{Pi/2, Pi}, {0, 2}, {0,  1}},
 {{Pi, 3 Pi/2}, {0, 2}, {0, 1}}, {{3 Pi/2, 2 Pi}, {0, 2}, {1, 1}}, 
 {{Pi/2, Pi}, {0, 2}, {1, 2}}};
colors = ColorData[54, "ColorList"][[;; 5]];

cylindricalSectors[colors, specs]
```

[image]

```
random = Transpose[{Sort /@ RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, {7, 2}],
     {0, #} & /@ RandomReal[{1, 3}, 7], Sort /@ RandomReal[{0, 10}, {7, 2}]}];
colors = ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Range[1/7, 1, 1/7];
cylindricalSectors[Opacity[.7, #] & /@ colors, random]
```

[image]