# Setting a range of values to one value

Tags: replacement

My question is perhaps worded a little vaguely, but it's a problem I'm running into defining my own function. I'm drawing some shapes with variable height, and sometimes this height is 0. For it still to draw something, inside my function I used the replacement

```
(0 -> 0.01)
```

However, in reality I'm using heights determined from some numerical function, which means that instead of 0 I'll get something like $10^{-14}$. For most purposes still very much zero. What I'd like to do is do the above replacement for a range of numbers, say in this case, all numbers between 0 and 0.01 get mapped to 0.01. Is that possible?

Comment: `/. x_ /; x <= .01 -> 0.01` ... or `Clip[{.021, 2, 3}, {0.01, Infinity}]`, where `{.021, 2, 3}` is some example list, etc.

Comment: Removed my comment, I made a mistake myself, give me a second. I think your solution is all I needed.

Comment: Hm, what's the protocol for when your question is answered in the comments? Do I just close it somehow?

Comment: Nah, just leave it, if the community votes to close, it will close...

Comment: Alternatively you can post an answer to your own question. It's encouraged to acknowledge the helpful comment.

Comment: maybe it's just a coincidence, but if you are referring to the substitution I used in the [`makePie`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85322/27539) function, you can just as well leave it there: you can pass a $10^{-14}$ argument to it without problems.

Comment: @glance It was indeed related to that. When I fed it a 10^-14 argument, I got a rather weird surface when looking from the top, kind of pixalated or oily or something. I could give a specific example, but this fixes it. I guess the issue came from giving it an opacity with almost 0 thickness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you are looking for is Chop[]. Wrap it around anything and it will act at all levels to replace everything under $10^{-10}$ with zero. There is an optional second argument to adjust the tolerance. Then you can just do your /.{0->.1}